Can databricks live table with joins be incrementally updated?
Can a Databricks live table with joins like the example below be updated incrementally, or does it need to be fully re-computed every time, similar to how Redshift materialized views with joins require full refreshes?
import dlt

@dlt.table(
    name="summary_table",
    comment="Anonymized summary data"
)
def summary_table():
    return spark.sql("""

            SELECT 
                tA.col1,
                tB.col2 AS colB1,
            ...
            FROM table_A AS tA
            JOIN table_B AS tB 
                ON tB.id = tA.b_id 
            LEFT JOIN table_C AS tC 
            ...


Does this answer your question? https://docs.databricks.com/en/optimizations/incremental-refresh.html
